# Are xsl-fo-elements part of xsl-files?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I try to understand how the workflow is to convert xml in html and pdf from a single source. I understand what a xml-file is, how it is structured etc. I understand what a dtd or a schemm is doing. And I also understand what a xsl file is doing, in case I want to convert xml in html. I know that from this files a xslt-processor is making a fo-file in case one wants to convert xml in pdf.

What I don´t understand so far is, if I need two xsl-files when I want html and pdf - one for every format. I guess not. But are then the fo-elements part of the same xslt-file, which defines the html-structure? If so, how are fo-elements are mixed with xslt-elements?

Hope I was clear in my description.
Thanks for help,
Pjoern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate HTML and PDF files from a single XML source document, you would typically have separate XSLT transformations for

- **XML-to-HTML**
- **XML-to-XSL:FO** (which would then be used to generate PDF)

Yes, there will usually be HTML elements in the  **XML-to-HTML** XSLT and XSL:FO elements in the **XML-to-XSL:FO** XSLT used to generate PDF.

Think of XSLT as the generic XML transformation engine and XSL:FO as a particular XML vocabulary designed to be converted to PDF.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That was my question - if there are two xsl-files, one for xsl-fo (for pdf)  and one for html. Now its clear: yes. Thx.

Comment: Of course, there may be scope for some code to be shared between the two stylesheets. In that case there are two ways of doing it: one is to have a common module included/imported into both. Another way is to have a pipeline of multiple transformations: first do the generic transformations (e.g grouping or sorting), then the transformations that are specific to a particular output format.